# Is there a Bitcoin calculator /price tracker widget to add to Gnome?

Tags: gnome, bitcoin

Is there a way to add something like an online [Bitcoin to USD calculator](https://coinvigilance.com/btc-usd-rate/) to the Gnome desktop? I don't think the Software store has anything like that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Askubuntu! What version of Gnome-Shell are you currently using?

Comment: GNOME Shell 3.18.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gnome-shell-extension available for Gnome Shell that does this.

---

First, install `gnome-tweak-tool`, `gnome-shell-extensions`, and the gnome-shell-integration "native hosts" package `chrome-gnome-shell` by running the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool gnome-shell-extensions chrome-gnome-shell
```

Reboot before you proceed.

---

Next, go to the [bitcoin-markets](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/648/bitcoin-markets/) official-gnome-shell-extension homepage and install the bitcoin-markets extension.

Finally, open the application "gnome-tweak-tool" (it might be listed as "tweaks") and click on the "extensions" tab on the left and make sure that the extension is enabled here (there should be a toggle switch for each extension listed).

---

Please post any errors or problems you encounter. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, I got it to work! Thanks so much! Yeah it's called "Tweaks" in my distribution. Thanks again!